# Где взять полный актуальный список всех стандартных тегов и классов для editor-style.css?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Нужно заполнить `editor-style.css`.

И сразу возник вопрос: есть ли полный актуальный список всех стандартных тегов и классов для `editor-style.css`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все возможные варианты вы можете посмотреть в [примере](https://cdn.wpsmackdown.com/wp-content/themes/smackdown2/editor-style.css) Дейва Фарфела к его полному руководству к функции `add_editor_style` под названием "[How to Add Custom WordPress Editor Styles](https://wpsmackdown.com/custom-wordpress-editor-style/)".

Мне кажется, это наиболее полное руководство (больше, чем в Кодексе) и самый полный пример стилей.

Comment: хороший ответ, спасибо за ссылку на статью, от меня тоже плюс :)

Comment: А откуда он взял теги и классы? Почему нет официального полного актуального списка?

Comment: Tinymce это вендорный проект, поэтому такие вещи следует смотреть на их официальном сайте, а по ссылке в ответе наиболее полный в рамках WordPress

Comment: Чтобы понять, откуда он это взял, поставьте плагин Tinymce Advanced, чтобы активировать полный функционал редактора. Затем добавьте в контент все возможные блоки. Откройте dev tools вашего браузера и проинспектируйте полученную страницу. Там увидите все классы. В WordPress нет мануала, так как он юзает только малую часть возможностей tinymce и классы эти иногда меняются. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил

Comment: Если ваша задача получить одинаковое отображение страницы в админке и на сайт-советую смотреть не в сторону визивигов, которые отмирают, а в сторону gutenberg https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/. Эта разработка войдёт в ядро WordPress 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Кнопки и действия редактора WordPress задаются в файлах

```
wp-includes/js/quicktags.js
wp-admin/js/editor-expand.js
wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wordpress/plugin.js
```

Разбирайте js, смотрите, как срабатывают кнопки, задавайте стили.

Comment: Так вроде вопрос был по стилям)

Comment: @mihdan да, кнопки задают h1-h6 и т.д. Можно на них навесить стили. Изначальная задача ТС (сформулированная в другом вопросе) была в том, чтобы привести в соответствие стили в tinymce и style.css, чтобы статья в tinymce выглядела так же, как и на сайте.

Comment: @mihdan мне не было известно никакого руководства на данную тему, поэтому я копнул исходный код WordPress. Ваш ответ лучше, я его плюсанул.

Comment: понятно. Спасибо за плюсы)

Comment: А вот ещё файл `wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/wordpress/wp-content.css`. Как я понимаю, это стили по умолчанию для редактора?

Comment: Ага, это именно оно